# Show Filename of uploaded files in "Field Collection" Field

Tags: search, entities, views

I have a requirement where I have to show files uploaded within a category.[image: Fields]. I used Field Collection Module of Drupal for it and made fields in the following way, where each category is a field collection item which has a title field and a multi value file field:-

[image: Field Collection Fields]

Now, my end result is to show it in a Search Results Page. When someone searches for a keyword, and it matches the uploaded filename, the file should show in the Search.

I tried views, etc, but I can't output it. Any help please on how to output the file names for the search keyword through Search Results in Drupal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a search display using Display Suite (https://drupal.org/project/ds). By enabling DS and DS Search you will get some search options done through DS.